# T-SQL Parse String and Perform Actions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am exploring options to dynamically calculate values based on a string input. Take for example the following string input.

```
"(32+35)/(12+34)"
```

The numbers 32, 35, 12, and 34 are "placeholders" for IDs. In spoken language what I am trying to do is as follows. Take the metric with ID 32 and apply some function to it which returns a value. Then add that value to the value returned by the same function applied to metric id 35, so on and so forth.

```
(dbo.foo(32) + dbo.foo(35)) / (dbo.foo(12) + dbo.foo(34))
```

It might be easier to start with a simple addition string and work into taking other operators (-,/,*).

Is this possible in tsql? Open to regex options (have a regex tsql function) and anything else you can think of.

Perhaps a regex replace on integers to insert the function name into the string would work and then exec() the string to get a result?

Let's not argue the pros/cons of such a method...i know this is not a true "database" solution to my problem but want to explore it more.

Comment: You may not get a lot of useful responses since you basically say "I know this is a bad solution but want to do it anyways".  I can ask a question on automotive.se about the best way to lubricate my engine with sand, but that doesn't mean I shouldn't expect to be corrected.  **Good luck!**

Comment: JNK, you are certainly correct. However I never said I thought this was a bad solution, just not a "true database" solution. Certain situations warrant different solutions and without a full background on my issue I don't think you can judge one solution over another.

Comment: Sure we can judge it. The judgment might not be accurate without knowledge of the specifics in your situation, but the vast experience of many people on here leads me to think that if they have concerns even without the hidden specifics that you're probably going in the wrong direction. I'll also add that pretty much everyone thinks that their situation is unique enough to warrant violating conventional wisdom. In my experience most of them are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work as a proof of concept using the regex option I mentioned.

```
    declare @str as nvarchar(1000)
    declare @regex as nvarchar(1000)

    set @str = '(32+33)/(12+93)'
    set @regex = 'select ' + dbo.regex_replace('\d+','dbo.foo($&)', @str, 1, 0)

    exec(@regex)
```

My regex_replace function takes parameters (@pattern, @replacement, @subject, @global, @multiline). I found this function via google. If you are searching it is "RegexReplace" I believe.

This code provides the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The RegEx is quite elegant. But partly because not everyone has RegEx available and partly because I had already put in all the work, here is a straight T-SQL solution (not the most robust, and horrible variable names, but it gets the job done). Note that it assumes whole numbers - if you throw decimals in there you'll have to check for those too.

```
DECLARE 
    @foo NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'(32+35)/(12+34)', 
    @bar NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

DECLARE 
    @i INT = 0, 
    @z INT = LEN(@foo), 
    @y INT, 
    @s NVARCHAR(12),
    @s2 NVARCHAR(12);

WHILE @i <= @z
BEGIN
    SET @s = SUBSTRING(@foo, @i, 1);
    IF ASCII(@s) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
    BEGIN
        SET @bar += 'dbo.foo(';
        SET @y = @i + 1;
        WHILE @y <= @z
        BEGIN
            SET @s2 = SUBSTRING(@foo, @y, 1);
            IF ASCII(@s2) BETWEEN 48 AND 57
            BEGIN
                SET @s += @s2;
                SET @y += 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                BREAK
            END
        END
        SET @s += ')';
        SET @i = @y - 1;
    END
    SET @bar += @s;
    SET @i += 1;
END

PRINT @bar;

--EXEC('SELECT ' + @bar);
```

Comment: I like this solution as well. Fairly easy to follow even with the variable names. Good stuff. No decimals...the integers would represent an ID column in a DB table.